Can't get a simple biber/biblatex command to generate citations and a bibliography (on TeXstudio)
I'm using a simple setup. I am taking point from Overleaf's very simple example (in link "Open this example in Overleaf").
The problem is that while the files work fine and render as expected in Overleaf, it does not render at all on my set up. It took me several hours of working on my syllabus to realize that the problem isn't my code, it must be something else. So I reproduced the problem with the aforementioned Overleaf sample file.
I am using TeXstudio on Linux Mint. LaTeX was installed over apt. I am using pdfTeX, none of the fancier Lua or Xe stuff since I can't make sense of it yet.
I have tried several searches for this issue, but I have yet to find a solution in previous questions online.
The .tex and .bib setups are as follows (literally copied and is the same on Overleaf and on my PC):
main.tex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Welcome to Overleaf --- just edit your LaTeX on the left,
% and we'll compile it for you on the right. If you open the
% 'Share' menu, you can invite other users to edit at the same
% time. See www.overleaf.com/learn for more info. Enjoy!
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
]{biblatex}
\title{A bibLaTeX example}
\addbibresource{sample.bib} %Imports bibliography file

\begin{document}
\section{First section}

Items that are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book \cite{latexcompanion} together with Einstein's journal paper \cite{einstein} and Dirac's book \cite{dirac}---which are physics-related items. Next, citing two of Knuth's books: \textit{Fundamental Algorithms} \cite{knuth-fa} and \textit{The Art of Computer Programming} \cite{knuth-acp}.

\medskip

\printbibliography
\end{document}

sample.bib
@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
  keywords =     "physics"
}

@book{dirac,
  title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
  author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
  isbn={9780198520115},
  series={International series of monographs on physics},
  year={1981},
  publisher={Clarendon Press},
  keywords = {physics}
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts",
    keywords  = "latex"
}
 
@online{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html",
    keywords  = "latex,knuth"
}

@inbook{knuth-fa,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   title = "Fundamental Algorithms",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   year = "1973",
   chapter = "1.2",
   keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}

@book{knuth-acp,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   title = "The Art of Computer Programming",
   series = "Four volumes",
   year = "1968",
   note = "Seven volumes planned",
   keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}

@article{ctan,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351",
    keywords  = "latex"
}

Expected render
This was produced on Overleaf itself.

Render that comes out of
This is my render on my PC using TeXstudio

Solutions I've tried
Command line
I tried a solution from WikiBooks that uses the command line instead of TeXstudio doing it for me:
latex latex_source_code.tex
bibtex latex_source_code.aux
latex latex_source_code.tex
latex latex_source_code.tex

Note: of course I changed the relevant filenames in my attempt.
Tweak how the .bib file is read
I tried using \bibliography{sample.bib} instead of \addbibresource{sample.bib}. I saw some discussion of this on previous online searches. Unfortunately, there was no change.
Logs of note
Citation 'latexcompanion' on page 1 undefined
Citation 'einstein' on page 1 undefined
Citation 'dirac' on page 1 undefined
Citation 'knuth-fa' on page 1 undefined
Citation 'knuth-acp' on page 1 undefined
Empty bibliography
There were undefined references.
Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) main(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

These logs were produced by TeXstudio. I can somewhat read the logs, but the errors make no sense given the manual and instructions available. Citations and references are defined, the bibliography is not empty, yet it produces these errors anyway.
I know it says "rerun LaTeX" and I have run it several times. On command line. On TeXstudio. Reruning makes no difference.
Etc.
Again, these issues are absent on Overleaf. So this suggests the error lies in my setup somehow? But what issue I have with my LaTeX setup is really beyond me.
I have proved this issue is reproducible on more than one document (my initial try was a draft syllabus and my second try is the Overleaf sample).
Previously I got an error that said biber wasn't installed. So I installed biber over apt. Yet the logs do not indicate that there are missing packages.
Edit 1
I tried running biber instead of bibtex
latex main.tex && biber main.aux && latex main.tex && latex main.tex

Some of the errors are the same, but others in the output I do not understand.
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'latexcompanion' on page 1 undefined on input line 21.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'einstein' on page 1 undefined on input line 21.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'dirac' on page 1 undefined on input line 21.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'knuth-fa' on page 1 undefined on input line 21.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'knuth-acp' on page 1 undefined on input line 21.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 25.

[1] (./main.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                main
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )
Output written on main.dvi (1 page, 948 bytes).
Transcript written on main.log.
Use of uninitialized value in quotemeta at /usr/share/perl5/Biber/Config.pm line 228.
Use of uninitialized value $tool in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Biber/Config.pm line 307.
INFO - This is Biber 2.17
INFO - Logfile is 'main.aux.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find 'main.aux.bcf'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1

Edit 2
Taking point from David Carlisle's suggestions, I modified the command to be so:
pdflatex main.tex && biber main && pdflatex main.tex && pdflatex main.tex

Result
The result looks closer to what I expect

Pending issues
I would like to still make TeXstudio produce the correct output rather than use command line. Is there a way to do this?

Overleaf uses latexmk, which runs LaTeX plus other tools, potentially several times. Here, have you run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX?

you are using biblatex so should use biber not bibtex for the second step (or use latexmk to call the commands for you)

@JosephWright What does TeXstudio use? Would running compile or build and view be equivalent?

@DavidCarlisle I ran latex main.tex && biber main.aux && latex main.tex && latex main.tex I got the same errors, but there were some output I didn't understand. I'll post it on main.

biber main not biber main.aux  would be the usual call. Oh ues that's what the error message you just added means

also you should be using pdflatex not latex to get a pdf file not a dvi file (most likely, certainly that is what overeaf does)

@DavidCarlisle I've updated the post with edit 2. Seems like your suggestion worked. But if possible, I'd like to still get this to work on TeXstudio. Is there a way to do that?

texstudio is just the editor that you use to edit the text it does not actually process the files so whatever button or menu you press must somewhere list which commands to run so yes you can fix that (but I don't have texstudio so someone else would have to show you that) if you search this site for texstudio configuration there are plenty of examples

Ah well, thanks anyway, this is a big help. The issue isn't my specific LaTeX setup but with TeXstudio.

Use Tools->Commands->Latexmk from the texstudio menu bar. That's what overleaf uses behind the scenes and it will do all the necessary compilation steps automatically.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I tried that but it had some issues for some reason. Probably need to look more into it.

@theienzo Can you show your texstudio preferences, in particular the "Commands" and "Build" tabs?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz using latexmk results in Error: Could not start the command: latexmk -pdf -silent -synctex=1 "main"
Command is set as latexmk -pdf -silent -synctex=1 %
Can I put images on comments?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz seems like latexmk isn't installed, that's why it didn't work.

@theienzo latexmk is normally part of all major latex installations. I'd guess your texstudio just can't find it. That's why I would like to see your preferences.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I installed latexmk and it works as expected now! Thanks.

Command line
Running the command
latex main.tex && biber main.aux && latex main.tex && latex main.tex

produces output as expected.
The problem is that TeXstudio was using the wrong automatic commands to render the file. Inputting the above commands manually instead of through TeXstudio rendered the file correctly.
TeXstudio
My friend alerted me of editing the TeXStudio Settings. I reconfigured build to use Biber instead of biblatex. This got the base document to be rendered as expected on TeXstudio. There seems to be other (unrelated) issues when changing the style=alphabetic to style=chicago-authordate, but this seems to be unrelated to the issue at hand.
SOLVED.
Thanks everyone.
